# How to Update, Where Exists and Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-update, distinct, exists

Hello I am trying to perform an update on a table only the records of "DISTINCT" but is updating all records, can someone help me?
Thank you very much.

```
UPDATE  SC20101
SET     SC20101.C2_OBS  =   'Ok'
FROM    SC20101
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT D3_OP, SC2.C2_DATRF, SC2BKP.C2_DATRF,SC2BKP.C2_OBS
    FROM SD3010 SD3 
        LEFT JOIN SC2010 SC2 ON SC2.D_E_L_E_T_=' ' AND C2_FILIAL = D3_FILIAL AND D3_OP = C2_NUM + C2_ITEM + C2_SEQUEN
        LEFT JOIN SC20101 SC2BKP ON SC2BKP.D_E_L_E_T_=' ' AND SC2BKP.C2_FILIAL = D3_FILIAL AND D3_OP = SC2BKP.C2_NUM + SC2BKP.C2_ITEM + SC2BKP.C2_SEQUEN
    WHERE SD3.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' AND D3_OP <> ''
    AND D3_EMISSAO BETWEEN '20200801' AND '20200831'
    AND SC2.C2_DATRF IS NULL
    AND D3_CF = 'PR0')
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: It does not seem like you `EXISTS (...) ` uses the original `SC20101` table at all. Normally this would be included in `WHERE SC20101.--- = ---` without adding the table itself to the join statement in `EXISTS`. Said in another way: Remove the last join statement and add it to the `WHERE` statement.  
`Where [--] AND SC20101.D_E_L_E_T_= ' ' AND SC20101.C2_FILIAL = D3_FILIAL AND D3_OP = SC20101.C2_NUM + SC20101.C2_ITEM + SC20101.C2_SEQUEN`. This is prone to my own errors from just very quickly looking it over.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (ANSI SQL has no UPDATE FROM.)

Answer (score 2):

`EXISTS` returns true if *any* row is returned in the subquery (the columns don't make a difference).  You are using `LEFT JOIN`, so your `EXISTS` is equivalent to:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SD3010 SD3)
```

Well, approximately.  The filtering conditions might have some impac.

I am guessing that you intend a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE  SC20101
SET     SC20101.C2_OBS  =   'Ok'
FROM    SC20101
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM SD3010 SD3 JOIN
         SC2010 SC2
         ON SC2.D_E_L_E_T_=' ' AND C2_FILIAL = D3_FILIAL AND
            D3_OP = C2_NUM + C2_ITEM + C2_SEQUEN 
    WHERE SC20101.D_E_L_E_T_=' ' AND
          SC20101.C2_FILIAL = D3_FILIAL AND
          D3_OP = SC20101.C2_NUM + SC20101.C2_ITEM + SC20101.C2_SEQUEN AND
          SD3.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' AND
          D3_OP <> '' AND
          D3_EMISSAO BETWEEN '20200801' AND '20200831' AND
          SC2.C2_DATRF IS NULL AND
          D3_CF = 'PR0'
   );
```

You haven't qualified all the column names but I think this is query you want.

Comment: thank you
selecting only the distinct loads the records correctly but when inserting in the WHERE EXISTS it updates the everything = x table.
I tried to follow your directions but returned only 1 record